# colspan on cell do not work on collapse table when display none and again display: table-cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem is when I click on the button then the cell I collapsed. That works. Then when I click one more time, then the row is colspan-1 in spite of colspan-3. What should I do to make row colspan 3 when click again. Look on border for cell a.
This is live code https://jsfiddle.net/dok6sxu4/8/

```js
const collapseDetailsTransaction = () => {
    const details = document.getElementById(`details`);
    const caret = document.getElementById(`collapse-button`);
    if (details.style.display === "none") {
      details.style.display = "table-cell";
      caret.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    } else {
      details.style.display = "none";
      caret.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    }
  };
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="collapseDetailsTransaction()" id="collapse-button">klik</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="details"><td colspan="3">a</td></tr>
</table>
```

[gif show this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB4IO.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`details.style.display = "table-cell";`

needs to be

`details.style.display = "table-row";`

Comment: Seems like the only problem it fixes is remove the outline of the lower row. `td` is still the same with.

Comment: @code I don't understand what you're saying. https://jsfiddle.net/58Lpys9c/2/ behaves just as expected. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Where did the second column from the second row come from?? It looks like the OP only wants one column, full width, on the second column.

Comment: @code I just added it for you to prove that the width of the first cell behaves as expected. Remove it and change cellspan to 3 and you have the solution to the initial problem. `details.style.display` is an object of type `tr`, while it was getting redeclared as `td` in the question.

Comment: I would vote up but I can't unless you edit.

Comment: @code No problem, thanks.